# Reduce the simulation time of a large scenario

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I simulated a large scenario (using the whole map of a city) with Omnet-5.0 , Veins-4.5 and SUMO-0.29.0.
The first scenario simulated took one week.

I need to know the computing time used by Veins comparing it to SUMO and Omnet++. I asked for SUMO, I have a response that SUMO takes 1 second to load the network and 0.3 seconds to run the simulation.

Is there a tool to reduce the simulation time of my scenario please?

Comment: Executing a single "run" took one week, or a campaign with numerous runs in it?

Comment: yes, executing a single run took one week.

Comment: Did you compile your Veins code with `MODE=Release` ?

Comment: Simulation run time depends on many factors. One of the most important factors are granularity (how detailed are your models) and scale (how many interactions are you simulating). You might want to use more coarse-grained models (for example, if you are interested in how a whole city behaves, you probably don't need to investigate how every single bit propagates through the network). The example simulation of Veins uses *very* detailed models. You might also want to investigate a shorter time frame or a smaller area. This is especially helpful during development, for quick trial runs.

Comment: @JulianHeinovski: thank you for your response. Should I delete veins and reinstall it by using ./configure and make MODE=release -j 8 commands and then reexecute the simulation?

Comment: You don't have to delete or do `./configure` again, just compile it with the `MODE` flags as you mentioned.

Comment: another option for speeding up the simulation is to not use the graphical interfaces of OMNeT++ and SUMO. To achieve this use `Cmdenv` for OMNeT++ when you execute your simulation run, and use `sumo` binary instead of `sumo-gui` binary in `omnetpp.ini`. You can find further details in the Veins FAQ regarding your question: http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/faq/ . At least two questions address "speed ups"

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply.

Comment: If your issue is solved, you might want to answer the question with the actual solution. This might help other users who face a similar problem in the future.